# setting a counter with a basic HTTP server

Tags: python, timer, webserver

Currently I have a basic HTTP server set up using `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` and I use the `do_GET` method of the same. Id like a function `check` to be invoked if a request does not come in for 5 seconds.

I'm considering using multiprocessing along with the time module for the same, but I'm concerned about its reliability. Are there any suggestions for best practices relating to the same?

Thanks.

[EDIT]

Marjin's solution is really cool but I end up with the following traceback :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 89, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 83, in main
    server.serve_forever()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 224, in serve_forever
    r, w, e = select.select([self], [], [], poll_interval)
select.error: (4, 'Interrupted system call')
```

[EDIT 2]
I tried it on Python 2.7 but the error still occurs.

[EDIT 3]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 90, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 84, in main
    server.serve_forever()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 225, in serve_forever
    r, w, e = select.select([self], [], [], poll_interval)
select.error: (4, 'Interrupted system call')
```

Comment: What do you need to happen when no requests has come in for 5 seconds? Is it okay to 'react' when it has been more than 5 seconds?

Comment: Id like to log something, kill a process and restart it. Could you please explain what you mean by react? Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can store the time of the most recent successful request, and when the *next* request comes in you can measure how much time has passed in between. If that's more than 5 seconds you can log something, kill a process and restart it, etc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That sounds good but the issue would be that I'm not sure if a _next_ request would come, at all.(sorry if i was unclear earlier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple server such as one based on `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` you could use a signal handler:

```
import time
import signal
import sys

last_request = sys.maxint  # arbitrary high value to *not* trigger until there has been 1 requests at least

def itimer_handler(signum, frame):
    print 'itimer heartbeat'
    if time.time() - last_request > 300:  # 5 minutes have passed at least with no request
        # do stuff now to log, kill, restart, etc.
        print 'Timeout, no requests for 5 minutes!'

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, itimer_handler) 
signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, 30, 30)  # check for a timeout every 30 seconds

# ...
def do_GET(..):
    global last_request
    last_request = time.time()  # reset the timer again
```

The `signal.setitimer()` call causes the OS to send a periodic `SIGALRM` signal to our process. This isn't too precise; the `setitimer)` call is set for 30 second intervals. Any incoming request resets a global timestamp and the `itimer_handler` being called every 30 seconds compares checks if 5 minutes have passed since the last time the timestamp has been set.

The `SIGALRM` signal will interrupt a running request as well, so whatever you do in that handler needs to finish quickly. When the function returns the normal python code flow resumes, just like a thread.

Note that this requires at least Python 2.7.4 for this to work; see [issue 7978](http://bugs.python.org/issue7978), and 2.7.4 is not yet released. You can either download the [`SocketServer.py` file that will be included in Python 2.7.4](http://hg.python.org/cpython/raw-file/e44fa71d76fe/Lib/SocketServer.py), or you could apply the following backport to add the `errorno.EINTR` handling introduced in that version:

```
'''Backport of 2.7.4 EINTR handling'''

import errno
import select
import SocketServer


def _eintr_retry(func, *args):
    """restart a system call interrupted by EINTR"""
    while True:
        try:
            return func(*args)
        except (OSError, select.error) as e:
            if e.args[0] != errno.EINTR:
                raise


def serve_forever(self, poll_interval=0.5):
    """Handle one request at a time until shutdown.

    Polls for shutdown every poll_interval seconds. Ignores
    self.timeout. If you need to do periodic tasks, do them in
    another thread.
    """
    self._BaseServer__is_shut_down.clear()
    try:
        while not self._BaseServer__shutdown_request:
            # XXX: Consider using another file descriptor or
            # connecting to the socket to wake this up instead of
            # polling. Polling reduces our responsiveness to a
            # shutdown request and wastes cpu at all other times.
            r, w, e = _eintr_retry(select.select, [self], [], [],
                                   poll_interval)
            if self in r:
                self._handle_request_noblock()
    finally:
        self._BaseServer__shutdown_request = False
        self._BaseServer__is_shut_down.set()


def handle_request(self):
    """Handle one request, possibly blocking.

    Respects self.timeout.
    """
    # Support people who used socket.settimeout() to escape
    # handle_request before self.timeout was available.
    timeout = self.socket.gettimeout()
    if timeout is None:
        timeout = self.timeout
    elif self.timeout is not None:
        timeout = min(timeout, self.timeout)
    fd_sets = _eintr_retry(select.select, [self], [], [], timeout)
    if not fd_sets[0]:
        self.handle_timeout()
        return
    self._handle_request_noblock()


# patch in updated methods
SocketServer.BaseServer.serve_forever = serve_forever
SocketServer.BaseServer.handle_request = handle_request
```

Comment: @MartjinPieters Hi, it seems I'm having a "select.error: (4, 'Interrupted system call')" when I do that.

Comment: Ah, the SIGALRM interrupted your socket select. Then it's incompatible with using `select()` on sockets, which uses OS interrupts as well.

Comment: Hrm, the `select()` code in `SocketServer` already catches that option. What is the traceback for that? In a pastie somewhere would probably be best.

Comment: @uki: Ah, you are using Python 2.6; this has been fixed in Python 2.7. Can you upgrade, or should I include a backport in my answer?

Comment: I just tried it on 2.7, but it does not seem to fix the problem.

Comment: @uki: Same exception? Can you update the exception line? I see there was a bugfix for this exact exception included in Python 2.7.3.

Comment: @uki: Mea culpa, the fix I am looking at was added *after* 2.7.3 was tagged. That same day, in fact. Updating to include a backport.

Comment: @MartjinPieters Cool thanks, the error does not happen at this point, but the SignalHandler does not get invoked either. Should I filing a bug report somewhere?

Comment: @uki: I need to investigate this a little more, sorry about that.

Comment: @uki: I tested the code as it stands now, and I see the signal handler being invoked, and working as designed.

Comment: @uki: Updated to use `setitimer()` to have the OS give us a periodic signal.